# Troubles with proving R is an equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, integers

With $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, I'm trying to prove that the relation $R$ defined on $A\times B\,$ by $(a,b)R(c,d)\,$ iff $\,ad=bc$, is an equivalent relations.

While I do see why reflexivity and symmetry hold, I have troubles with transitivity. Could you please give me a clue?

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail?

Comment: pick (a,b), (b,c) and (e,f) in $A\times B$ and apply the premises. Do you see the result?

Comment: There is a clue - have a look at the web. I found several proofs immediately.

Comment: **First step.** Write out the interpretations of $(a, b)R(c, d)$ and $(c, d)R(e, f)$ and lastly $(a, b)R(e, f)$. Are you able to do that? If so, are you able to conclude the third interpretation if you accept the first two interpretations as true? If not, please add to your post where you get stuck with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was misunderstanding transitivity. but I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a,b),(c,d), (e,f)\in A\times B$ and assume that $(a,b)R (c,d)$ and $(c,d)R(e,f)$. The aim is to show that $(a,b)R(e,f)$, i.e. that $af = be$. For, note that
$$ad = bc$$
and

$$cf = de$$
and $b$ and $c$ are non-zero. Now observe that

$$
adf = (ad)f = (bc)f = b(cf) = b(de) = bde,
$$

and so $adf = bde$, which can be rearranged to
$$
d(af-be)=0.
$$ Since $d\in B$, it follows that $d \neq 0$. Therefore, the zero product property for integers implies that $af-be=0$, which implies $(a,b)R(e,f)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I was misunderstanding transitivity. but I see it now.

Comment: Since you're working in $\Bbb Z$, how you define the multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @SineoftheTime, this answer seem correct to me. Can you please explain why you disagree?

Comment: Again, you can't divide by $d$, as dividing is equal to multiply by the inverse

Comment: No, but integers are a particular case of the rationals which do possess an inverse.

Comment: @yahiro your relation is a subset of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, and multiplying by the multiplicative inverse does not hold since the inverse is not in the set you're considering

Comment: @SineoftheTime, if you're worried about a circularity in the construction of $\Bbb Q$, this really isn't a problem, since it's a relatively easy theorem that in $\Bbb Z$, whenever $a \ne 0$ and $ab = ac$, we have $b = c$. The proof of this depends on how you construct $\Bbb Z$, but should be an easy consequence of the corresponding fact for $\Bbb N$, which can be proved by induction. But I don't think this level of technicality is required at all for this question. If you do accept that $\Bbb Q$ exists, then it is totally valid to calculate in $\Bbb Q$ to deduce an equality in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I think it's wrong to say "dividing both sides" or "multiply by the inverse".

Comment: @SineoftheTime  I'll rephrase the wordings but as aslo stated by IzaakvanDongen, here I really have in mind the Cancellation property of the integers, i.e. if $ab=ac$ and $a\neq 0$, then $b=c$.

Comment: @SineoftheTime Happy with the edit?

Comment: @utobi The main problem is that we don't know the contest of the question, so it may be an exercise from an Abstract algebra course or a random exercise that do not require more sophisticated knowledge. Anyways, your answers is correct

Comment: @MikeEarnest Sure :)